# Authentication problem doesn't log in even if i pass the correct email and password

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, error-handling

I tried to log into the system with the email and username I previously registered; however, I'm not able to log in successfully. I also attempted to debug it with Visual Studio Code, but I didn't find any errors while debugging. There were no errors in the browser console either. I will provide the code that I believe is crucial for understanding the context

```
Entrar.js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Entrar.module.css';

const Entrar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  const [dados, setDados] = useState({
    email: '',
    senha: '',
  });

  const [erro, setErro] = useState("");

  const handleMudar = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    setDados({ ...dados, [input.name]: input.value });
  };

  const handleEnviar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = 'http://localhost:5555/autenticar';
      const { data: resultado } = await axios.post(url, dados);
      localStorage.setItem('token', resultado.token);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (erro) {
      if (
        erro.response && erro.response.status >= 400 &&
        erro.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setErro(erro.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.entrar_container}>
      <div className={styles.entrar}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
          <form onSubmit={handleEnviar} className={styles.form}>
            <h1>Entrar</h1>
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              name='email'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.email}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Senha"
              name='senha' // Changed to 'senha' from 'password'
              onChange={handleMudar}
              value={dados.senha}
              required
              className={styles.input}
            />
            {erro && <div className={styles.erro_msg}>{erro}</div>}
            <div className={styles.button_container}>
              <button type="submit" className={styles.entrar_btn}>
                Entrar
              </button>
              <Link to="/entrar/cadastrar">
              <button className={styles.novo_aqui_btn}>
                Novo Aqui?
              </button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entrar;

autenticarRotas.js
/* Importa os módulos necessários */
const express = require('express');
const { Usuario }  = require('../models/usuario');
const Joi = require('joi');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const autenticarRotas = express.Router();

autenticarRotas.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const { error } = validar(request.body);
        if (error) 
                return response.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        
        /* Verifies if exist a user with the email */
        const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({ email: request.body.email });
        /* if doesn't exist returns a message */
        if (!usuario) 
                return response.status(400).send({ message: "Usuário não encontrado" });
        
        /* Verifies if the password or email is correct */
        const senhaValida = await bcrypt.compare(
            request.body.senha, usuario.senha
        );
        if (!senhaValida) 
                return response.status(400).send({ message: "Senha ou email incorreto" });

        const token = usuario.generateAuthToken();
        response.status(200).send({ dados: token, message: "Login efetuado com sucesso" });
    } catch (error) {
        return response.status(500).send({ message: "Erro interno do servidor (autetica rota)" });
    }
});

/* Cria um validação de dados usando joi*/
const validar = (dados) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string().email().required().label("Email"),
        senha: Joi.string().required().label("Senha"),
    });
    return schema.validate(dados);
};

/* Exporta a route */
module.exports = autenticarRotas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't import axios

```js
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot it. But the login process still doesn't work because i still getting error password or email incorrect and gives the error 400 in the console browser

Comment: At least now you're actually making requests and you're able to see the response from the server. You have a problem with your password because you're entering in this condition `if (!senhaValida)`

Comment: Make sure you input the expected password. Decrypt the password from your database and see if it is what you're expecting.

Comment: But this if (!senhaValida) is used to verify if the user given by the user is different from valid so the will print this message

Comment: The "!" is a negative affirmation

Comment: Yes, what I meant is `senhaValida` is false. Hash your `request.body.senha` and see if is the same as what you have in `usuario.senha`

Comment: This is already in the code * Verifies if the password or email is correct */
        const senhaValida = await bcrypt.compare(
            request.body.senha, usuario.senha
        );

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab from your dev tools. Do you see the request you are trying to do? This might give you a hint about your problem. Another thing you can do is console log the entire axios response, maybe you are getting something you are not expecting there.

Comment: I don't see any response from the network look at this https://imgbox.com/1Re3GGhi

Comment: I fixed the problem was import I forgot to import dotenv